Optimal Methods for Storing and Retrieving Chroma Vector Store in AWS S3 for a RAG Chatbot
I'm currently developing a RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) chatbot that relies on ChromaDB as its vector store. The application features two main components: an admin page for uploading PDF documents, converting them into vectors using ChromaDB, and storing these vectors in AWS S3; and a chat page where users interact with the chatbot.
My objective is to streamline the process of converting PDF documents into Chroma vectors during upload and seamlessly integrating these vectors into AWS S3 for efficient retrieval in the chatbot. However, I've encountered challenges with serializing and deserializing Chroma vectors, particularly when attempting to store them in SQLite3.
I'm seeking advice on best practices for handling Chroma vectors in a cloud environment like AWS S3. Should I continue exploring SQLite3 for storing serialized vectors, or consider alternative solutions such as FAISS for better performance and scalability? Any guidance or recommendations, especially for someone new to this field, would be greatly appreciated.
snippets of serialisation -
def create_sqlite_database(db_conn, documents):
    # Create a table and insert data into SQLite
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS embeddings (
                        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        document_id TEXT,
                        embedding BLOB
                    )''')

    # Insert data into the table
    for doc_id, embedding in enumerate(documents):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO embeddings (document_id, embedding) VALUES (?, ?)",
                       (str(doc_id), pickle.dumps(embedding)))

    db_conn.commit()



USAGE OF THIS FUNCTION -

USAGE OF THIS FUNCTION -
def extract_and_store_embeddings(bucket_name, pdf_key, region='ap-south-1'):
    try:
        # Print debugging information
        st.write(f"Bucket Name: {bucket_name}")
        st.write(f"PDF Key: {pdf_key}")
        st.write(f"Region: {region}")

        # Load the PDF documents from S3 using Amazon Textract
        loader = AmazonTextractPDFLoader(f's3://{bucket_name}/{pdf_key}', region_name=region)
        st.write("Loader initialized")
        text_documents = loader.load()
        st.write("Documents loaded")

        # Split documents into chunks
        txt_spt = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=100000, chunk_overlap=10000)
        documents = txt_spt.split_documents(text_documents)
        st.write("Documents split into chunks")

        # Initialize Chroma DB and embeddings
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
        st.write("Embeddings initialized")
        db = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings, persist_directory="./chroma_db")
        st.write("Chroma DB created")

        # Create a temporary SQLite database
        temp_db_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.sqlite')
        db_conn = sqlite3.connect(temp_db_file.name)
        st.write("SQLite database connected")

        # Insert data into SQLite database
        create_sqlite_database(db_conn, documents)
        st.write("Data inserted into SQLite database")

        # Move SQLite database to a backup location
        #
        #shutil.copy(temp_db_file.name, backup_file)
       # st.write(f"SQLite database '{temp_db_file.name}' backed up successfully to '{backup_file}'")

        # Upload the backup SQLite file to S3
        s3key = f"{os.path.splitext(pdf_key)[0]}.backup.sqlite"
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        s3_client.upload_file(temp_db_file.name, bucket_name, s3key)
        st.success(f"SQLite backup uploaded to S3 at s3://{bucket_name}/{s3key}")

        return db
except boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError as e:
        st.error(f"S3 upload failed: {e}")
    except NoCredentialsError as e:
        st.error(f"No AWS credentials found: {e}")
    except PartialCredentialsError as e:
        st.error(f"Partial AWS credentials found: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

